# Django database routing parameter transmission problem

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
class AuthRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        params = hints.get('params')
        return 'default'


    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        params = hints.get('params')
        return 'default'
```

I want to pass some parameters to **hints, but I don’t know how to do it, can you tell me, thank you very much！

I tried the following methods, but none of them work

```
# read
TestModel.objects({'params': 'Hello World'}).filter()  # {TypeError}'UserManager' object is not callable

TestModel.objects.filter(hints={'params': 'Hello World'})  # {FieldError} Cannot resolve keyword 'hints' into field ...



# write
TestModel.objects.filter().first().save(hints={'params': 'Hello World'})  # {TypeError}save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hints'
```

Comment: Try to use `db_manager` like: `TestModel.objects.db_manager(hints={'params': 'Hello World'}).filter()`